# SCOPE_IDENTITY - procedure calling another procedure to make insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure (let's say `sp1`) which executes some code to check if passed parameter does not violate business rules. After validation it calls another stored procedure (say `sp2`) which actually inserts the record in a table.

My question is whether I can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in `sp1` to get the `IDENTITY` inserted in the table by `sp2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` provides the latest id from a scope, so as soon as the sql hits a "`GO`" a new scope is created and you wouldn't receive the identity, you could add an output parameter on sp2 to receive the identity which is probably the best way.

Answer (score 3):

As Joakim says, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will not return the identity from the second procedure. From the MSDN docs on [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch.
>   Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the
>   same stored procedure, function, or batch.

`@@Identity` does behave to way you want but has the major downside that it picks up the latest identity inside the current connection **including triggers**. Even if you are 100% certain that there are no triggers acting on the relevant tables, anyone adding a trigger later on will break this, introducing a tricky to find bug so given how simple using an output parameter is, I'd really advise against `@@Identity`.

Comment: Even if there are no triggers now, adding one later will break this if you use @@Identity.

Comment: @HLGEM I did write "and that there never will be" but I will edit to make that point clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You create an output parameter to hold the identity value you want in the proc doing the insert. And podpulate it with scope_identitiy or the results of an output clause.

Then you create a variable of the same name in the calling proc and call the proc this way:

```
exec @id = usp_my_proc @someinputvariable, @someotherinputvariable
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always strive to *encapsulate* whenever possible.  Not only *can* SP2 return the new scope identity value; SP2 *should* return the new scope identity value.  It can be returned as a RETURN value or as an OUT parameter.

Always best to avoid globals.